# (ArgumentError) expected to: to be given as argument

Tags: elixir

Good day. I have weird `ArgumentError` in my code even tho the code looks very fine.
I'm Following the project from `Mastering Elixir`book.

```
defmodule ElixirDrip.Storage.Provider do
  @moduledoc false

  @target Application.get_env(:elixir_drip, :storage_provider)


  defdelegate upload(path, content), to: @target
  defdelegate download(path), to: @target
end
```

**The error**

> ** (ArgumentError) expected to: to be given as argument

Answer (score 2):

In the environment, you *compile* this code the `:storage_provider` is not set. You should have been warned about `Application.get_env/3` on the module level should not be used (`Application.compile_env/3` is to be used instead.)

Make sure you have the storage provider set in the environment you compile the code.

```elixir
@target Application.compile_env(:elixir_drip, :storage_provider)

if is_nil(@target), do: raise "MUST BE SET: provider"
```

Comment: For an unknown reason it returns `nil`. I have a `config` set up in `apps/appName/config/config.exs` and `apps/appName/config/prod.ex` like this `config :elixir_drip,
  storage_provider: ElixirDrip.Storage.Providers.GoogleCloudStorageLocal
` for some reason it still can't find `:storage_provider`. Should i manually tell him where to look for config files or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: MIX_ENV=prod mix compile

Comment: i've tried following this guide https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html but still got the `runtime error` of `provider` not being set

Answer (score 1):

`to:` is [supposed to be a module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2). I guess you need something like:

```
defdelegate upload(path, content), to: Application, as: :get_env
```

Comment: The issue is most likely `@target` is `nil` in the respective compile environment.